# HTTP/2 is here. Complete list of what we should do to adapt our websites and webapps?

Tags: web, web-applications, http2

HTTP/2 is here. Browsers [adopted it already](http://caniuse.com/#feat=http2) and major web servers should all support it within 2015.

What is the **complete list** of what we should do (or stop doing) to adapt our websites and webapps, both from the front-end and back-end points of view?